# How to change severity of lack of using statement in Jetbrains Rider?

Tags: c#, rider

How do I change severity of `put into 'using' statement` suggestion? I'd like to have it treated as warning. Currently it is only available as context action.

[image: image of context action]

I tried searching for this setting in `Editor > Inspection Settings > Inspection Severity > C#`, and in [Jetbrains docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html), but I could not find any info regarding this setting. Is it even possible to change this?

Comment: This is more the job of a linter rather than the IDE

Comment: @OneCricketeer but if IDE is able to give me this suggestion, this means it is aware that this object implements `IDisposable`, therefore it should be possible to configure severity of this suggestion.

Comment: It is aware. Thus giving a suggestion, but it's not going to be a compiler / lint warning.

Comment: I'm genuinely surprised that this isn't a compiler warning... If you want this added as an inspection severity option, I'd suggest you raise something on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: I don't expect this to be a compiler warning, I simply want this to be visible without having to click on the variable (underlined with yellow line). Rider can do it with other hints, which are not compiler warnings - e.g. I can set `Use var (built-in types)` severity to warning or even error, although this is not a compiler warning.

Comment: @KifoPL - Yeah I know what you're wanting... I use Rider as my primary IDE, I'm just surprised it's not a compiler warning

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, you cannot change the severity of this issue with Rider.

We're the Roslyn analyzer [IDisposableAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/IDisposableAnalyzers) for these issues.